# What are some of the best free puzzle rush apps?

Tags: learning, software, puzzles, recommendations

I'm looking for a puzzle rush app that's free and does not require a subscription. I tried using the Chess.com app, but there's a limit on the number of times you can play in a day.

Comment: What counts as a "puzzle rush app"? Maybe try ChessBase puzzles or chesstempo

Answer (score 5):

Check out https://blitztactics.com/ which is pretty much the same thing.
It even has a few other modes.

Comment: This site is amazing thank you ,I'm loving the repetition mode

Comment: I also believe that blitztactics was available before chess.com came up with puzzle rush.

Comment: Not exactly an app, but you should be able to access on mobile without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend Max Chess: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dim.maxym.mychess

You can choose difficulty of puzzles and time mode.